# Mysql SHOW CREATE USER fails with error 1396, but user exists

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to dump the users of a mysql server. Generally it works, but for a certain user, I get this error:

> mysql> show create user 'usercacti'@'localhost'; ERROR 1396 (HY000):
> Operation SHOW CREATE USER failed for 'usercacti'@'localhost'

but the user exists; the following query to the `mysql` database

```
mysql> select * from user where User='usercacti' and Host='localhost';
```

returns 1 row.

I connect as root; Mysql 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

What could be the problem?
Thanks

EDIT: as requested by Ergest Basha:

```
mysql> show grants for current_user();

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ABORT_EXEMPT,AUDIT_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FIREWALL_EXEMPT,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SENSITIVE_VARIABLES_OBSERVER,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO `root`@`localhost`
GRANT PROXY ON ``@`` TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: What is the result of `show grants for current_user();` ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha see edit above

Comment: Have you restored the mysql schema ? In other words is the mysql imported ?